# Simplify Test while comparing enums

Tags: java, enums, refactoring, simplify

I have some test code that looks like:

```
@Test
  public void testEnums_AB() {
    // arrange + act
    var enums_1 = Arrays.stream(enumsA.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    var enums_2 = Arrays.stream(enumsB.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // assert
    Assertions.assertEquals(enums_1, enums_2);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEnums_CD() {
    // arrange + act
    var enums_3 = Arrays.stream(enumsC.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    var enums_4 = Arrays.stream(enumsD.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // assert
    Assertions.assertEquals(enums_3, enums_4);
  }
```

... and so on.

I am thinking about how to simplify the patterns to have the logic only once, something like:

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} => enum1={0},enum2={1}")
  @MethodSource("parametersProvider")
  public void testEnum(enum enum1, enum enum2) {
    // arrange + act
    var enumsBlah = Arrays.stream(enum1.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    var enumsFoo = Arrays.stream(enum2.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // assert
    Assertions.assertEquals(enumsBlah, enumsFoo);
  }
```

But (of course) this example is not even compilable.

Does anyone have an idea to avoid the repeating structure for these enum checks?

Comment: Extract these two lines in another method and call that.

Comment: @GauravJeswani then do you know how to abstract the specific enums in the methods parameter list?

Comment: @DerBenniAusA I have put my answer. I think this is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getEnumConstants` like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testEnum(TestEnum.class, AnotherTestEnum.class);
    }

    private static <T extends Enum<T>, T2 extends Enum<T2>> void testEnum(Class<T> enums1Class, Class<T2> enums2Class) {
        var enums1 = Arrays.stream(enums1Class.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        var enums2 = Arrays.stream(enums2Class.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        // compare here
    }

    private enum TestEnum {
        A, B
    }

    private enum AnotherTestEnum {
        A, B
    }
}
```

As a JUnit 5 test:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class EnumTest {
    private static Object[][] parametersProvider() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {TestEnum.class, AnotherTestEnum.class}
        };
    }

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} => enum1={0}, enum2={1}")
    @MethodSource("parametersProvider")
    <T extends Enum<T>, T2 extends Enum<T2>> void testEnum(Class<T> enums1Class, Class<T2> enums2Class) {
        var enums1 = Arrays.stream(enums1Class.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        var enums2 = Arrays.stream(enums2Class.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Assertions.assertEquals(enums1, enums2);
    }

    private enum TestEnum {
        A, B
    }

    private enum AnotherTestEnum {
        A, B
    }
}
```

Comment: looks very nice, I will try that

Comment: Add a JUnit 5 based example now as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your line of

```
var enums_1 = Arrays.stream(enumsA.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

should use a method. Assuming that you have a method called `testifyEnum`, which would get an `enum` parameter and calculate the right-hand side of your assigning, you will only need to do:

```
var enums_1 = testifyEnum(enumsA);
```

so your code will look like this:

```
@Test
  public void testEnums_AB() {
    // arrange + act
    var enums_1 = testifyEnum(enumsA);
    var enums_2 = testifyEnum(enumsB);

    // assert
    Assertions.assertEquals(enums_1, enums_2);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEnums_CD() {
    // arrange + act
    var enums_3 = testifyEnum(enumsC);
    var enums_4 = testifyEnum(enumsD);

    // assert
    Assertions.assertEquals(enums_3, enums_4);
  }
```